# A conditional expression to differenciate between an existing and non existing object?

Tags: r

Package Caret,

I have a model I call model1, model1 can have three outcomes depending on the data set:

```
model1 <- train(X[train,], Y[train], method='bag', trControl=myControl, preProcess=PP)
```

model1 yields a RMSE result.

```
model1
Pre-processing: centered, scaled 
Resampling: Cross-Validation (2 fold) 

Summary of sample sizes: 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

nprune  RMSE    Rsquared  RMSE SD  Rsquared SD
2       0.0419  0.0556    0.00279  0.0392     
7       0.0419  0.0549    0.00244  0.028      
12      0.042   0.0417    0.00214  0.0196     

Tuning parameter 'degree' was held constant at a value of 1
RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were nprune = 7 and degree = 1.
```

model1 produces a RMSE with NA.

```
model1
Pre-processing: centered, scaled 
Resampling: Cross-Validation (2 fold) 

Summary of sample sizes: 32, 33, 32, 32, 32, 32, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

nprune  RMSE    Rsquared  RMSE SD  Rsquared SD
NA       NA       NA       NA          NA     
NA       NA       NA       NA          NA  
NA       NA       NA       NA          NA
```

model1 produces an error as below and yields a non existing model1

```
+ Fold1.Rep1: vars=3 
model fit failed for Fold1.Rep1: vars=3 Error in bag.default(trainX, trainY, vars =    
tuneValue$.vars, ...) : 
entrada en evaluacion: recursivo por defecto o problemas anteriores?

model1
Error: objeto 'model1' no encontrado
```

I would like to be able with a conditional expression to differenciate between the three results. I can do it between a RMSE of NA or a RMSE with a number result.

```
if(model1$results$RMSE[1]=="NA")0 else model1
```

However when model1 fails as in the third case I cannot find a way to put together any conditional expression as the model does not exist, however I would like to be able to differentiate  model1 when it does not exist, model1 when it produces a RMSE result and model1 when it produces a RMSE with NA. Would you happen to know if I can differentiate a non-existing object from an existing object by means of a conditional expression?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `exists` and `is.na`:

```
if (!exists("model1")) {
  # Model not built
} else if (is.na(model1$results$RMSE[1])) {
  # Model built with NA
} else {
  # Model built properly
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe `exists` or `"results" %in% names(model1)` is what you are looking for.